# Quickbook : name supplied already exists error

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

We are facing some issue while we are syncing customer information with Quickbook API,

We are getting error like "**The name supplied already exists. : Another customer, supplier, or employee is already using this name. Please use a different name.**"

We have checked All three (customer, supplier, employee) listings in quickbook online. but I can't find record which already inserted and can't show in lising.

how I can find , are there any other listing need to check ? We checked customer, supplier, employee already with Include Inactive option.

Comment: Contact QuickBooks support if you can't find the customer/vendor/emplyee with the same name, even when searching for "inactive" things too.  This is not an appropriate question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks Keith for replying , Yes I'll post in Quickbook forum

Comment: Where do you apply the query to access the quickbook database?